# How long do I have to wait for poop?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I need to get coprite for my base's farm. All the farm specialist is telling me that it comes from "overfeeding" creatures.

However, I can't seem to overfeed them - I feed them once, and they smile and cavort, but then I can't feed them again. I've hung around a while, but no coprite seems to appear.

Is this just a case of "wait longer" - is it a random thing (in which case, should I just feed as many animals in the herd as possible?). Or is it specific animals (so far, I've only been feeding small herbivores)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait time on excrement is between 30 seconds to one minute, on average.

After you feed a creature the substance it craves, a smiley face appears and it may run off. Either keep visual track of the creature and wait for a label to appear indicating the animal has left you a "gift" or press use the search function and look for the icon on your HUD.

Comment: I was hanging around for a good five minutes last night - went on again tonight and, yeah, less than a minute...